# PHP Regex How i can determined / check preg_match find single value or multiple values

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match

in PHP Regex How i can determined or check preg_match find single value or multiple.

I mean if preg_match find multiple values then do this else if it find single value then do this

```
<td class"page"> 
<span class="my-tag">value1</span>
<span class="my-tag">value2</span>
<span class="my-tag">value3</span>
<span class="my-tag">value4</span>
</td>
```

Now when I use `preg_match` like as

```
preg_match('/<td class"page">(.*?)<\/td>/s', $page, $string);
```

and if `$string` contain `4 values` it means it find multiple values then do echo `"mutliple values"`;

else

```
<td class"page"> 
<span class="my-tag">value3</span>
</td>
```

Now I use

```
preg_match('/<td class"page">(.*?)<\/td>/s', $page, $string);
```

and if it `$string` has `1 value` it means it find single value then do `echo "single value"`;

Your help will be appreciated!

Comment: Regex is not the correct tool for parsing HTML/XML instead you can use `DOMDocument`

Answer (score 0):

The `preg_match` returns the `$string` variable as an array, so you can check for the size of the array and take a desition from there. e.g.

```
if(count($string) == 1) {
 // found one result
} else if (count($string) > 1) {
 // found multiple results 
} else {
 // not found results
}
```

More information about [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)! in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match()` will return an array of matches in `$string` and you can use `count()` to determine the number of values in that array. The solution would look something like this:

```
if('/<td class"page">(.*?)<\/td>/s', $page, $string){
    //a match was found
    if(count($string) > 1){
        //multiple matches were found

    }
    else{
        //only one match was found
    }
}
else{
    //no matches were found
}
```

P.S. `sizeof()` is an alias of `count()`